# String randomly replaces from u003d' to '='

Tags: c#

I got returned string with some unencode characters, but want to keep then as is, just strangely C# converts automatically u003d to =, how to prevent that? Replace doesn't work, because it's really the same...

```
string val = "{\"signature\":\"ME8AE6I\u003d\",\"protocolVersion\":\"ECv1\",\"signedMessage\":\"{\"encryptedMessage\":\"QyJot2n/C2Dtlc\\u003d\",\"ephemeralPublicKey\":\"BES5/vMn0p/k8\\u003d\",\"tag\":\"4vGw\\u003d\"}\"})";      
        Console.WriteLine(val);
```

Basically returning:

```
{"signature":"ME8AE6I=","protocolVersion":"ECv1","signedMessage":"{"encryptedMessage":"QyJot2n/C2Dtlc\u003d","ephemeralPublicKey":"BES5/vMn0p/k8\u003d","tag":"4vGw\u003d"}"})
```

as you see it's wrong: ME8AE6I= and \u003d replaced with \u003d

How to solve that?

Dotnet fiddle example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PiNYOs

Comment: Your example already includes the way to fix it. Do you see how later in the output string there is a `\u003d`? Do you notice something about the number of slashes in the input at that location?

Comment: what is expected return value?

Comment: .Replace("\u003d", "\\u003d") still leaving last one \\u003d with one slash

Comment: expected {"signature":"ME8AE6I\u003d","protocolVersion":"ECv1","signedMessage":"{"encryptedMessage":"QyJot2n/C2Dtlc\\u003d","ephemeralPublicKey":"BES5/vMn0p/k8\\u003d","tag":"4vGw\\u003d"}"})

Comment: Please re-read my comment. You've already demonstrated a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`\u003d` is considered as a unicode character so C# auto converts it to `=`
but `\\u003d` is not a unicode character becuase `\` is escaped(using another `\`)

```
String val = "\u003d";
String val2 = "\\u003d";
Console.WriteLine(val);//outputs =
Console.WriteLine(val2);//outputs \u003d
```

Replace `=` with `\u003d` using normal Replace method
and then replace `\\u` to `\u`(except = sign) using `Regex`

```
String val = "{\"signature\":\"ME8AE6I\u003d\",\"protocolVersion\":\"ECv1\",\"signedMessage\":\"{\"encryptedMessage\":\"QyJot2n/C2Dtlc\\u003d\",\"ephemeralPublicKey\":\"BES5/vMn0p/k8\\u003d\",\"tag\":\"4vGw\\u003d\"}\"})";
            //{"signature":"ME8AE6I\u003d","protocolVersion":"ECv1","signedMessage":"{"encryptedMessage":"QyJot2n/C2Dtlc\\u003d","ephemeralPublicKey":"BES5/vMn0p/k8\\u003d","tag":"4vGw\\u003d"}"})
Regex replacer = new Regex(@"(?<![\\])([\\]{1})[u]{1}", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
val = replacer.Replace(val,"\\\\u");
val = val.Replace("=",@"\u003d");       
Console.WriteLine(val);
```

Output:

```
{"signature":"ME8AE6I\u003d","protocolVersion":"ECv1","signedMessage":"{"encryptedMessage":"QyJot2n/C2Dtlc\\u003d","ephemeralPublicKey":"BES5/vMn0p/k8\\u003d","tag":"4vGw\\u003d"}"})
```

.NET Fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/YPWVdM